# Riemann sum with midpoint integral not accurate enough

Tags: c

I tried to write a function to calculate the Riemann sum of a given function with the midpoint rule. I have to reach a minimum accuracy which is determined by a test function. Unfortunately my function is either wrong or not accurate enough. I cannot change the step width to increase accuracy.

```
double midpoint(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, double h)
{ //f: given function; a: lower limit; b: upper limit; h: step width
   
    double integral = 0;

    double new_a = a;
    int x = 0;
    
    while (new_a + h < b)
    {
        new_a = a + (x * h);
        if (new_a >= b) break;
        integral += h * f(new_a + (h/2));
        x++;
    }
    
    double s = b - new_a;
    integral += s * f(new_a + (s/2)); 
    return integral;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. That would include a complete runnable program, the desired output, and the actual output.

Comment: Your problem is that you consider the last "full" section twice, because when your loop condition `new_a + h < b` is false, `a_new` isn't updated and `s` is not the rest but `h` plus the rest. You can fix that by either updating `new_a` last thing in the loop (like `x`)  or by saying `while (1) ...` and letting the `break` condition terminate the loop. (The two redundant conditions are a bit suspicious.)

Comment: Read https://floating-point-gui.de/ - see also [these slides](https://calcul.math.cnrs.fr/attachments/evt/2019-06-precision-num/support11.pdf) (by colleagues)

Comment: @MOehm : Thanks! I didn't consider that `a_new` doesn't get updated. That solved my problem. Originally i had the two conditions because i got a weird behaviour from the condition of the `while` loop. Even though i considered the condition as false the loop ran again in some cases (not everytime). And with the second condition i got rid of that. Now i just let the `break` condition terminate the loop like you suggested.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks, that explains the weird behaviour i observed from the `while` loop i guess.

Comment: I think it is all correct if you update new_a after x++

Answer (score 1):

Here you are updating to the new a which in the last iteration of the loop is too far.

```
new_a = a + (x * h);
```

And here you are using it incorrectly to calculate the last part.

```
double s = b - new_a;
integral += s * f(new_a + (s/2));
```

Let us look at an example call `midpoint(somefunction , 1.0, 2.0, 0.4)`.

These are the values processed inside the loop:

| x | new_a (while) | to | new_a (if) | increment for integral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | .. | 1.4 | 0.4 * f(1.2) |
| 1 | 1.4 | .. | 1.8 | 0.4 * f(1.6) |
| 2 | 1.8 | .. | 2.2 | 0.4 * f(2.0) |

Then the while condition prevents the loop from iterating again.
At that point however, `new_a` is already 2.2.

Then we get `s` as `b-new_a`, which is -0.2 (note the negative).
And the integral is changed by -0.2 * f(2.2-0.2).

So in total the integral ends up as
0.4 * f(1.2) +
0.4 * f(1.6) +
0.4 * f(2.0) -
0.2 * f(2.0)

where the last two are equal to 0.2 * f(2.0) but should be 0.2 * f(1.9).
This introduces an error into the last product of the difference between the midpoint of the last narrower rectangle and the last `new_a` which might be up `h` above `b`.

To fix change your loop body to not increment `new_a` in the last iteration and to otherwise increement at the end of the loop:

```
        integral += h * f(new_a + (h/2));
        x++;
        if ( a + (x * h) < b) new_a = a + (x * h);
```

With the example you get:

0.4 * f(1.2) +
0.4 * f(1.6) +
0.2 * f(1.9)